# EDI X12 EO810 Data Extract with a space as ending position.

Tags: find, edi

I have an EDI document field that I am attempting to extract data from.  The Customer part number is listed in PID05 after a #.  I am trying to pull out the data between "#" and " " and return it to var_ITNO. However, my var_EP isn't necessarily stopping at the first space.  Any help on how to correct this issue?

```
var_PID05 = SOURCE.EO810H01.EO810D01.EO810D12.PID05 
var_SP = Find(var_PID05, "#") + 1
var_EP = find( var_PID05, " ",var_SP) 
var_ITNO = MID( var_PID05 , var_SP , var_EP )
```

Comment: Why wouldn't your partner send the Customer Part number in the IT1 segment?  Putting it in the PID is bad practice.  What language are you using that is supporting the Find function?

Comment: @Andrew This is an EO810 from our system, and the Customer Part number is included in the Item Description (PID05).  I'm not trying to put it IN the PID, but pull it out of that field.

Comment: so your system is generating the 810, and you're trying to parse it and pull information out of it?  The 810 isn't coming from a trading partner?  What language are you using to parse it?

Comment: @Andrew I am trying to manipulate my 810 to put Customer Requested Data in the document they receive.  I am using LiasonECS Mapper to accomplish this.  They currently receive a flat file via FTP.

Comment: Oh, you're using Delta.  That's a good thing.  Use InStr instead of Find.  Make sure your source node is the PID.  InStr will return the position of the space.

Comment: @Andrew I will try it!  I saw that but find says it is the exact same as find.  Thank you for your help, I'll update when I have something!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98172/discussion-between-allideacon-and-andrew).

Comment: @Andrew that, unfortunately didn't correct my issue.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code was specifying the space position for the Length.

```
`var_ITNO = MID( var_PID05 , var_SP , var_EP )`
```

I reworked it to read as follows:

```
`var_PID05 = SOURCE.EO810H01.EO810D01.EO810D12.PID05 
var_SP = InStr(var_PID05, "#") + 1
var_EP = InStr( var_PID05, " ",var_SP) 
var_LEN = var_EP - var_SP
var_ITNO = MID( var_PID05 , var_SP , var_LEN )`
```